# Request exceed the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My htaccess is as below:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# remove .php from URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L] 

# restrict .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /[^\ ]+\.php($|\ )
RewriteRule \.php$ / [F,L]

# remove .html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301] 

ErrorDocument 404 /error-page
ErrorDocument 403 /error-page 

RewriteRule ^good-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /goodie?
sd=$1&sd=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^goodies-([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ /goodie_new?
sd=$1&ds=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /goodie_new?
ds=$1&sd=$2&de=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^blog/([^/.]+)/?$ /blogdetail_fm?prmn=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !cityres
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /cityres?cityf=$1 [L]
```

When i access `blog` rewrite URL i.e. `http://example.com/blog/title-of-blog` then i am getting `500 Internal Server Error`. I tried adding `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$` but still 500 error is not disappearing.

Please let me know errors and if there is any wrong rules in myhtaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error-page
ErrorDocument 403 /error-page 

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [L,R=301]

# skip files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# restrict .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php($|\ )
RewriteRule \.php$ / [F,L]

# remove .html
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301] 

RewriteRule ^goodies-([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ goodie_new?sd=$1&ds=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^good-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ goodie?sd=$1&sd=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^blog/([^/.]+)/?$ blogdetail_fm?prmn=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ goodie_new?ds=$1&sd=$2&de=$3 [L,QSA]

# remove .php from URL
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond $1 !cityres
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ cityres?cityf=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: That worked like charm but now my css is disturbed as my base URL is now `http:example.com/blog/style.css`. I tried `<base href="/" />` on page but still CSS is not getting applied. M generating URL as `$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
$parts = explode('/',$url);
$dir="http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($parts) - 1; $i++) { 
 $dir .= $parts[$i] ."/";
 
}`

Comment: Are you using relative URLs for css/js? Can you use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`. `<base href="/" />` should have helped also.

Comment: my URL says `<link href=<?php echo $dir; ?>css/style.css` ... $dir gives URL as `http://example.com/blog/` by above rule in PHP

Comment: Rewrite rule cannot change your PHP code. It can redirect to some other URL but it is not doing that in rules either.